# javascript variable as subscript in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, subscript

I can't find this answer anywhere. I am learning javascript on myself so I guess this is basic.

I want to assign a variable "count" as the subscript of an array.

```
var firstnumber = 200;
var count = 1;
var a;
a[count] = firstnumber;
```

therefore to achieve the result as a[count] = 200

is there anyway to do this?

Comment: yes, what @juvian said.

Comment: Or `var a = new Array;`

Comment: Btw, if `a` was initialised as an array you'd have an array with two elements, `a[0] === undefined, a[1] === 200`.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your variable and initialize it as an array

var a = [];

Comment: That would be a [*VariableDeclaration*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2) with optional *intialiser*, in this case an [*Array initialiser*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.4). :-)

Answer (score 0):

See the comments below:

```
var a = new Array();  //create an Array
var count = 0;  //arrays start at index 0
var firstnumber = 200;
var secondnumber = 300;

a[count] = firstnumber; //set the first element of the array to firstnumber

count = 1;
a[count] = secondnumber; //set the second element of the array to secondnumber

alert(a[0]);  //displays 200 in an alert window
alert(a[1]);  //displays 300 in an alert window
```